# Simple way to avoid current draw on resistor divider sense?

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-measurement

This is a simple, but complicated question.

I measure voltage on several lines, more than 3'000. The lines can be up to 100V.

I only need to measure at certain time, and would like to avoid current draw from the sense lines when it's not being measured.

I was thinking to use a mosfet and detach the whole VSS from the bottom side of the resistor divider, but the AN are connected to sampling logic, which has internal protection diodes to 3V3, so it will still draw current.

Given that I have a lot of those lines and the application is cost sensitive, I would like to avoid to have a P Mosfet on each line with the resistors and zener that would be needed.

Is there some trick possible in here ? Maybe some component made for it I don't know about ?

[image]

---

Update:

The answer of Edgar Brown is valid, but is a bit complicated to drive the gate, given the voltage of the mos will vary.

Also I do not have space on the PCB to add mos between the two resistor of the divider (or would need to do quite a lot of re-routing).

I have another possible solution:

[image]

Q53 would decouple the sense divider from the ground and the other Q would decouple from the sensing IC.

If the gate of Q54 is driven as a open drain, Q53 would be driven first, bringing Q54 to a few V to VSS and then Q54 can be driven.

Only one resistor from all the Q54 gates to the Q53 Vd sould be enough?

---

Update 2

I think I found a better solution, adding a bias voltage before the VSense. Simply biased at the same voltage of the off state.

[image]

Comment: How much current draw is actually acceptable from each line? How much is too much? Be specific.

Comment: No current at all when off. or a few nano A.

Comment: That's a good answer. It excludes a continuous \$1\:\mu\text{A}\$. So you really do want to isolate the lines when not being observed. The cost-sensitivity now enters into the picture. What's your budget per measurement?

Comment: Do you need to be able to control the connection of each signal individually? Turning them all on and off together could dramatically reduce the number of extra parts needed for the PMOS solution.

Comment: Even controlling them in groups of 10 or so would mean only one zener/resistor/etc for each 10 lines.

Comment: They are all turned on together @ThePhoton, but they might have quite different voltages, although once all turned on, voltage would all be below 20V. It's a good point about having 1 zener for all, let me think for a minute.

Comment: Correct my previous comment, some channel can be turned on independently, but the measurement is always on alltogether. Please check my update.

Comment: @junk sorry didn't see your question, minimum as possible latest solution cost about 0.4 cent usd per channel.

Comment: Your added solution adds negative leakage current, which actually increases power consumption but now from your own supply (BTW a PMOS would be better in that application) so now I miss the point of why leakage is an issue.

Comment: Yes increased power consumption is not really a problem, and it's in the order of 80uA per channel. Leakage is an issue because on off state, there shouldn't be any current going through the load to which the channels are connected.

Comment: But now you have negative current going through the load. That is still leakage current, and it is different from "no current."

Comment: @EdgarBrown there is no current as the bias is the same voltage as the load is being supplied, so voltage across the load is (almost) 0V. Would NMOS work, as I already have it on the BOM.

Comment: @EdgarBrown using this implementation: https://imgur.com/a/3p3oHOj

Comment: @Damien that NFET is always off. Furthermore, after looking at your scheme more closely I don’t see how it would work unless there are some assumptions that are not shown in the schematics. Have you checked a simulation?

Comment: @EdgarBrown what would it be always off ? The gate would be brought at -3V3 in regard to the source and the NMOS would switch, MOS switch either with positive or negative gate voltage.

Comment: @Damien No, they don’t.

Comment: @EdgarBrown you are right, I don't know where I get that from. I changed to PNP BJT instead of PMOS for cost and availability reason. I think that should do it https://imgur.com/a/3p3oHOj

Comment: @Damien I still don’t see how this removes any leakage at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use NFETs as high-side switches under the 1M resistors. You might need an extra voltage to drive their gate, or to reduce your measurement range, but once you bias them in their triode region (which the 1M resistors make quite easy) their impedance will be negligible.

Just make sure to use a FET with low leakage across the reverse diode (or better yet, with a separate body connection) and to drive their Vgs to zero or negative when off, to stay out of the subthreshold region.

This is the basic idea. Assuming that each NFET is activated independently from each other.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD8jho.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PFETs could also be made to work. But their biasing is not as clean as (1) you would have to use the sources themselves to provide some of your gate biases, (2) you would need level shifters to reach 100V, and (3) you increase the leakage paths due to the level shifters. And any gate drive whatsoever will put you in subthreshold and that means leakage.

Comment: The problem would be to drive the gate of the NFET, it would need additional components not to break the Vgs max, each channel would need separate drive components, or I am missing something ?

Comment: @Damien that problem only happens with PFETs. You just need a supply that allows you to drive the NFET Gate at Vdaq_max + Vto + Vtriode. That could just be 5V above your DAQ supply which means you would just need a Vgsmax of 20V or so. Even gate clamps seem unnecessary due to the very high gain provided by the 1M resistors.

Comment: Good point, let me think about that option

Comment: I think your proposition is valid, but driving the gate might be a bit difficult, any positive voltage would bring the mos to a balance point, so would need some negative voltage, but this reduces the Vgs Max. Another problem, is I don't have space on the PCB to add mos on that area.

Comment: @Damien the space problem is an engineering decision, but you don’t need a negative voltage. All you need is a supply that lies more than a Vto above the maximum measurement range of the ADC. This can be solved by either an extra positive supply or by reducing the maximum voltage on the ADC.

Comment: Oh, I see. You misinterpreted my answer. I will add an schematic when I get to a computer later today. The NMOS drain and source have to be in series with the divider in between the two resistors, not in parallel to it.

Comment: @Damien I updated the answer to include a schematic.

Comment: Although it's not the solution I will choose, I will accept your answer as you had some effort into it. Thanks.